# How can I force an application to run with my dedicated Nvidia GPU using open source drivers

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, xorg, nvidia, nouveau

I'm using the open source Nouveau drivers, and I'd like to be able to run applications with my dedicated GPU, NVIDIA GeForce MX250 in X11.

Proprietary drivers are out of the question for me as they prevent me from logging in. I tried using prime-run but when i boot minecraft it shows me that it uses integrated intel graphics, and when i run `prime-run glxinfo | grep OpenGL`, It returns the following output:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I'm not sure what this means, but I'm sure its meant to output my dedicated GPU, which [shows up no problem in neofetch](https://imgur.com/a/SH1L4jm).

Sorry if a lot of this information is unnecessary, I don't want to miss anything out

Comment: Not sure what the prime-run command is.
But glxinfo | grep OpenGL provides similar output.

Comment: @JeremyBoden yep the output is the exact same

Comment: Please ask here instead https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I'm not using the nvidia drivers.